# How can I display PHP source code on Linux or similar?

Tags: php, file, system, move

I am trying to do `system("cat variables.php");` from a PHP script, but it doesn't write anything.

What's the problem?

Comment: Wait, what?  Do you want to edit it?  Or display it to users?

Comment: We're going to need a bit more here. In what capacity are you trying to display its code? On a webpage? On your local system? Is it even a file that belongs to you, or is it on another website?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to display the entire file to users, try:

```
highlight_file("path/to/file");
```

https://www.php.net/highlight_file

Comment: Its a file on my server and I want to output the entire php source code in my browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`file_get_contents`**](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to get the content of a file.

And you can use **`__FILE__`** to get the path to the current file -- if you want the current file, of course

So, to display the content of the current file:

```
echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);
```

Note 1: you might have to do some escaping:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(__FILE__)) . '</pre>';
```

Note 2: you can do that with any file, of course -- just **make sure the path to the file is correct**:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('/path/to/my/file.php')) . '</pre>';
```

And if you want more than just display the content -- if you want syntax-highlighting -- you could use the [`highlight_file`](https://www.php.net/highlight_file) function; or something like [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), which is richer and more configurable.

Comment: @Chacha : I thought about that after posting *(the idea proposed in the OP wasn't doing syntax-highlight either)* ; so I was editing when you posted your comment ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to step through your PHP code, use:

- http://xdebug.org/
- http://www.firephp.org/

These tools will allow you to view your variables at different points in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to display the contents of the file in its entirety some servers are configured to display the source of PHP files with a file extensions of phps. It will also syntax highlight the file's contents when displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone out there still needs the answer, put this anywhere in your code and it will display it with syntax highlighting.

```
show_source();
```

It should definitely work in PHP 5.0 and above.