# Display source of PHP of files

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im working on an upload script, and i want a user to be able to upload any file.
I had it al working on localhost, i added

```
    php_flag engine off 
    AddType text/plain php html shtml php5 php4 php3 cgi asp aspx xml
```

to my htaccess in the upload folder, and it showed the source of PHP, html and all other files. Exactly as i wanted to.
Now i tried to upload it to a real webserver, and unfortunately my host does not allow such .htaccess files.

I tried openinging the files with file_get_content() and fopen() and giving them a text/plain header.. but nothing works. It first executes the scripts and shows the output in my textarea.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how i can fix this without .htaccess ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display php source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561990/how-can-i-display-php-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't upload files into the webroot and let people access them directly. As you say, .php scripts (and probably a lot more) get executed that way. **A classic way for arbitrary code execution attacks.**

Store uploaded files outside the webroot where they're not publicly accessible and create a script that allows users to download the files, for example using [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) or Apache [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), after having done the necessary permission checks.

Also see [Security threats with uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads/11061577#11061577).

Comment: Ive stored them in a different folder, and i also have a download script that forces a download. But heres the thing, if a user uploads an mp3 file or movie, a flashplayer is loaded when accessing the file. Id like to show the raw contents of the PHP file in a <textarea> when someone has uploaded a php file.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question...?!

Comment: Nope, its the same i guess, i can give you an example if you want, to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Heres an example of an uploaded .JS file : http://www.dumpzor.com/n2mmji9cr9.dl

I want it to do the exact same when uploading .PHP files, just show the raw source of it in the textarea.

Comment: So, have a page with a `<textarea>` into which you dump `echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($thePhpFile))`...?

Comment: Yes, kinda like that!
I tried it using the highlight_file() function, but again, it executes the script instead of showing the highlighted version

Comment: It *executes* the file when running it through `highlight_file(file_get_contents())`?! I can guarantee you that it *doesn't*.

Comment: Youre right about that. Got the highlighted stuff working perfectly on local, but on the real server it does not output anything at all, could this be a .htaccess restriction again?

Yep.. this sucks : Warning: highlight_file() [function.highlight-file]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in

Comment: I got it fixed. I had the full URL to the file in my database, and my hosts didnt allow this. So i added the path to the file (without the domain), added that to the highlight_file() function and its working like a charm!